# How can I set the content offset of a FlatList in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, contentoffset

I know that we can get the offset with

```
render() {
   return <FlatList
            onScroll={this.handleScroll}
          />
}

handleScroll = (event) => {
//get offset by using   
//event.nativeEvent.contentOffset 
}
```

But I'm not sure how to set it

Comment: is this for ios or android?

Comment: @Akis ios, is it different?

Comment: just asking because `contentOffset ` is for ios only

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately contentOffset didn't work for me. I ended up using contentContainerStyle that I found in the ScrollView documentation and it works great.

```
<FlatList 
  contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop: 340 }} 
  data={data}
/>
```

Comment: contentContainerStyle is working for this situation.

Answer (score 3):

`contentOffset` accepts an object of type `{x: 0, y: 0}`:

In your case and if the list is vertical scrolling you should only set `y`

```
<FlatList
  onScroll={this.handleScroll}
  contentOffset = {{x: 0, y: your_value}}
/>
```

I haven't test this code but some users complain that setting the value will not work so they set the contentOffset value programmatically.

```
event.nativeEvent.contentOffset = { x: your_value }
```

Answer (score -2):

You may use ScrollToOffset(params)

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#scrolltooffset

or use ScrollTo(params)

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#scrollto